# Is there a way to create 3 installers(for windows mac linux) in one install.xml

Tags: maven, launch4j, izpack

I need to minimise the .exe application, because when generating the jar and then the exe, the exe application contains ressources of linux windows and mac. I want to generate 3 exe for each OS using just one installer.xml.

Comment: first of all .exe is a specified extension only for Windows, then, why you don't just use the jar file which is cross platform. The jar is executed on the jvm, so it doesn't contain resources of all operation systems, because it is executed on its own environment which is jvm.

Comment: have you found any way to create different three installer for windows, linux & mac?

Comment: found a solution to create 3 installers using 3 files of install.xml and then invoking those files inside the pom.xml of the izpack installer